# Submenu tree problem

Tags: 7, navigation

I have a website build with Drupal 7 CMS and I am using the [Submenu tree module](https://www.drupal.org/project/submenutree). Everything was working fine for months, but few weeks ago I have received a feedback from the client that all the links of sub and sublink content was disappeared. I have checked my local version of the website, and there are no any links also.

I have tried to use the same module on another local Drupal 7 website and the result is the same - no matter how I try to set it up - it does not show any sub or sublink content links.

Does anyone has the same problem? Anybody using the same module - can you confirm that it works fine with your website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this issue by reverting the module to an older version.As I see in the release notes

> Issue #3037177 by itcrowd72, omrmankar, troybthompson: PHP 7.2 each() function is deprecated

The php version I am still using is 5.6. It looks like the new module version is not ok with 5.6, or at least with my setup.